# Im trying to merge two linked lists into 1 linked list in ascended order

Tags: c++, class, singly-linked-list

I new to linked lists and need help understanding how know how to merge two linked lists together. Everything in my program works but the function to merge the two lists together in ascending order.
head and first are pointers to the start of two separate linked lists.

```
  void linkedListType::AscendMerge()
  {
    nodeType * c1;
    nodeType * c2;
    nodeType * p1;
    nodeType * p2;
    c1 = first;
    c2 = head;
    p1 = first;
    p2 = head;

    while (c1->link&&c2->link != NULL)
    {
      if (c1->info <= c2->info)
      {
        c1->link->link = c2->link;

      }
      if (c2->info < c1->info)
      {
        c1->link = c2->link;

      }
      cout << c1->info << " ";
      c1 = c1->link;
      c2 = c2->link;
     }
   }
```

Comment: My advice is spend some time with a pen and paper to draw what happens with the pointers.

Comment: Also It may help you to give better names to your variables. It is not necessary but it helps me sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your implementation. One has to do with the algorithm itself, and the second one has to do with the way it is coded in C++.

The problem with the algorithm is that your code does not deal with the "tails" of the lists: your `while` loop calls it quits as soon as one of the lists runs out of items, leaving the remaining items of the second list "orphaned".

Fixing this part is straightforward: all you need to do is linking the remaining non-null list to the end of the result.

The coding problem has several parts to it: first, your implementation is not receiving the two lists to be merged as parameters: both `c1` and `p1` are assigned `head`, presumably merging a list with itself. Second, your `while` loop stops before reaching the end of the list: `c1->link` being `NULL` means that `c1` is the final node; your code never examines its value. Finally, your code does not return the merged list. Your code does modify `link` values, but when the merge touches the `head`, the pointer is neither modified nor returned.